# Java private classes between sub-packages

Tags: java, oop

My Java library is made of a few sub-packages (com.example.lib.api, com.example.lib.imp, com.example.lib.util,...).

The classes in `api` use classes A and B from `imp`. The classes in `imp` use class C in `util`. 
I am forced to make `A`, `B` and `C` public, but I don't want them to be exposed to users of my library. Not hiding anything, my library is open source, but minimal APIs are simpler to understand.

Is there a way around it?

Comment: Why are you **forced** to make the *classes* `A`, `B` and `C` `public`?

Comment: Yeah, organize top level modules by feature, not by layers. That way you can use package visibility.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If `A` and `B` are not public, the classes in `api` can't access them.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce please elaborate.

Comment: Maybe you want to decouple your packages by introducing additional interfaces. E.g `A` could have package visibility, while implementing the public interface `Aalizable` required by `api`.

Comment: Essentially, if you want to hide them, then put them in the same package, and use package visibility instead of public.

Comment: @SME_Dev `Aalizable` would then be visible to users of the library, but really it's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java 9 you will be able to control which packages are exported from a JAR.  This way you can make them public, but not available to anyone else.

For now you can't control this.  You either put everything in one package or rely on the documentation to make it clear they should not be used. e.g. `jdk.internal` assumes no one should use these except the JDK.

Comment: In that case, would it make sense to create an annotation? `public @interface Internal {}`, then apply it to public and protected classes that should not be used by clients.

Comment: Or the reverse, a @PublicAPI annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a private class in any other package . Instead the class can be made public and the methods and variables can be made protected . So in this case the classes can be extended where they need and the contents in the class can be accessed only by the sub classes which extended it.

Comment: `You cannot use a private class in any other package ` You can, if the class implements a visible interface. E.g. think of the factory pattern. `methods and variables can be made protected ` is visible outside the library, because also clients can create subclasses.